# Convert an HTML source file to an XML file

Tags: php, html, xml

I use this code

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com');
```

But I want convert it to XML file then use some functions on it.
how can I do this?

I want to use this code. Can I?

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com'); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($doc) or die("Errooooooor");
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: Iterate over the elements and output the content as XML..

Comment: Just put your HTML as String into a DOMDocument Object. [Topic has been discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4881456/5482243)

Comment: [tagsoup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tagsoup/) is a SAX parser for HTML that may be useful here. See also [How to use JAXB with HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24791422/6002174), [parse any HTML to XML using html5lib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26717379/6002174) and [jTidy and TagSoup documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4452566/6002174).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to work with HTML in this case, with DOMDocument(); 
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com'); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: Alex thanks but when I use this for some domain it work but for some of them it dosent work.
why?

Comment: Alex i edite my question please read it a gain

Comment: `$xml=simplexml_load_string($doc) or die("Errooooooor");
print_r($xml);` - no, you cannot do this! In your case $doc is an object and simplexml_load_string() take a well-formed XML string as parameter. If you want parse your HTML, you can do like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881255/generating-xml-from-html-list-using-php](example)

Comment: Alex you are kind